# you can not add objects to a table

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

Good evening everyone,

As part of Javascript training, I have to present a project. While development,  I browse an array of objects with all the lines of a select query of SQL. Then
using the loop on each element of the table and then on each key to fill the fure and measure my object `infDb`

until all are correct before treating the 2nd element. I push my object `infDb` in the table `infVal2`

So, the problem is that after the 2nd push addition affects the whole array with the last value of the object.

I have an empty table:

```
var infVal2 = []
```

And an object:

```
var infDb = {
        "Name": "",
        "Qte": 0,
        "Marque": "",
        "Surv": 0,
        "Checked": false
    };

function loadData(data) {
    var infDb = {
        "Name": "",
        "Qte": 0,
        "Marque": "",
        "Surv": 0,
        "Checked": false
    };

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        var obj = data;
        // lors de la appel all, on boucle sur obj  qi est le tableau d'objet complet de la base

        obj.forEach((element, index) => {
            console.log("index :" + index + "-- element:" + element.Name);
            for (cle in element) {
                console.log("cle :" + cle + "-- element:" + element[cle]);
                if (cle === "Name") {
                    infDb.Name = element[cle];
                }
                if (cle === "Qte") {
                    infDb.Qte = element[cle];
                }
                if (cle === "Marque") {
                    infDb.Marque = element[cle];
                }
                if (cle === "Surv") {
                    infDb.Surv = element[cle];
                }
                if (cle === "Checked") {
                    infDb.Checked = element[cle];
                }
            }
            console.log("valeur :" + infDb.Name);
            infVal2.push(infDb);
        })
        return resolve();
    });

}
```

I did the console test directly first:

- on a simple table by adding a simple value from a loop ====> it works
- always from a loop but by adding an object ====> it does not work anymore

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Objects are passed by reference. Which means, each object in array of objects is pointing to the same object. When that one same object is modified, all the objects referencing it also get modified.

You can use [new Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) keyword or [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method